# appcelerator titanium app left and right nav button has extra space?

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, titanium, appcelerator

I am trying to add custom buttons to the left and right navButton but a spacer seems to appear if I set a backgroundImage. If only the title text is set the spacing is correct. Here is my example to reproduce the issue, I added a borderColor to show that the image is not the culprit.

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'white'
});
var leftBtn = Ti.UI.createButton({
    backgroundImage:"/images/headerCmdMenu.png",
    width: '81px',
    height:'74px',
    title: 'left',
    borderColor: 'red',
    borderWidth: 1
});
var rightBtn = Ti.UI.createButton({
    width: '81px',
    height:'74px',
    title: 'right'
});
win.leftNavButton = leftBtn;
win.rightNavButton = rightBtn;
var nc =  Ti.UI.iOS.createNavigationWindow({
    window : win
});
nc.open();
```

Here is a screenshot of the view…

http://imagebin.ca/v/13wq8Jrn1hst

Any ideas how to fix this?
Thanks.
Chris

Note: I did ask this on the official forums, but got no answer after 14 days.
http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/160022/leftnavbutton-and-rightnavbutton-spacer-appears-if-using-backgroundimage-#comment-196608

Answer (score 0):

This is quite long to answer but it might still help someone else looking for same issue.

For images in left/right nav buttons, look for the below points first:

1. If you only set title, then it will work as expected.
2. If you set only backgroundImage (not set width & height), then the image will be stretched to take the full space.
3. If you set only backgroundImage with some width & height, then the button will behave as a normal button with expected spacing and area.
4. If you set both backgroundImage & title, then it will be the case of this post.
5. Also remember that always use correct size image files when intend to use as left/right nav buttons.